# Google Maps API, add hover state to pin

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm creating a Marker layer on my Google Map, and then adding pins. These get added to this layer. I want to add a hover effect which is basically a circle behind the pin.

I was going to just use CSS, however I can't add a `before` or `after` to the image, so I need to get the parent element and add it to this. However the Google Maps API doesn't give you access to the Pin element.

```
var markerLayer = new google.maps.OverlayView();
markerLayer.draw = function () {
      this.getPanes().markerLayer.id='markerLayer';
};
markerLayer.setMap(_.map);

// Create pin and store it
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng),
   icon: marker,
   title: location.name,
   optimized: false
});
_.markers.push(marker);
```

Below is a screenshot of what the `marker` object contains, and as you can see there is no reference to the HTMLElement.

[image]

My only though was to search the `#markerLayer` div for images and storing them, assuming that these will appear in the same order as they are added to the `_.markers` property.

Or would a better way be to create a Circle using the API and putting it in the same position as the pin?

Answer (score 1):

I used the Google Maps Circle to create a circle shape, when hovering to markers.

here is the link to doc:
(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)

Check this addMarker function

```
function addMarker(position) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
    });

    var markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        center: position,
        radius: 500000
     });

     circles.push(markerCircle);
     markers.push(marker);

     marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
         var index = markers.indexOf(marker);
         circles[index].setMap(map);
     });

     marker.addListener('mouseout', function(){
        var index = markers.indexOf(marker);
        circles[index].setMap(null);
     });

     return marker;
}
```

I made a simple app, that will add markers by clicking on the map.

Check this working example: http://jsbin.com/nukecog/2/edit?html,js,output

```js
var map;
var markers = [];
var circles = [];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    addMarker(e.latLng);
  });
}

function addMarker(position) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });


  var markerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    center: position,
    radius: 500000
  });

  circles.push(markerCircle);
  markers.push(marker);

  marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    var index = markers.indexOf(marker);
    circles[index].setMap(map);
  });

  marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    var index = markers.indexOf(marker);
    circles[index].setMap(null);
  });

  return marker;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKQX3cyZ7pVKmBwE8wiowivW9qH62AVk8&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```